# Can to convert my local time to UTC in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert my local time to UTC. My code example is:

```
$s = '2017-06-08T18:00:00.000Z';

$d = new \DateTime($s, new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Vladivostok'));
print_r($d->getTimeZone());
$d = $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
print_r($d->getTimeZone());
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";
```

But I have invalid timezone on just created date time and converting return me same time.

Output:

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 2
    [timezone] => Z
)
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
2017-06-08 18:00:00
```

I can set timezone after creating

```
$s = '2017-06-08T18:00:00.000Z';

$d = new \DateTime($s, new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Vladivostok'));

//  Added
$d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Vladivostok'));

print_r($d->getTimeZone());
$d = $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
print_r($d->getTimeZone());
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";
```

But it not helps, I have correct timezone but time is same.

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Vladivostok
)
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
2017-06-08 18:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change time zone with a `DateTimeZone` object. Here's an example of this:

```
// INIT TIMEZONE OBJECTS
$utcTime = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$yourTime = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Vladivostok");

// CREATE DATA WITH YOUR TIMEZONE
$date = new DateTime("2017-01-01 15:00:00", $yourTime);

// ADJUST TIMEZONE TO UTC
$date->setTimezone( $utcTime );

// PRINT
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry Jay. Thank you for the input. Does the following edit help to better explain my answer?

Comment: Much better! Thanks!

Comment: Your date string is not looks like mine

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using date_default_timezone_set() and date_default_timezone_get() functions.

```
$date = strtotime("2017-06-15 00:00:00");
echo date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />";
echo date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$date) . "<br />";
echo date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />";
echo date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $date) . "<br />";
```